# What benefits does the two stage variant of Pollard's p-1 have? How is it different?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, factoring

There is a two [stage variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm#Two-stage_variant) of [Pollard's p-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm). In terms of application what is the difference between it and the normal one? Is the two stage variant faster? Is the only practical difference that it can find one more factor larger than the bound $B1$?

There are many two-stage implementations but I'm having trouble following the code. Some of the programming languages I don't get and some I suspect have bugs (because variables appear out of no where):

1. [Python example in Question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/183575/maximum-performance-for-pollards-p-1-function)
2. [Two more Python examples in Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424369/python-pollard-p-1-factorization/47965272#47965272)
3. [Scheme language implementation?](http://programmingpraxis.codepad.org/VpaXvPEN)
4. [Haskell language implementation](https://bonsaicode.wordpress.com/2010/03/19/programming-praxis-extending-pollard%E2%80%99s-p-1-factorization-algorithm/)

In the first few links there is a "cache", what does cache have anything to do with it?

Can anyone provide me with an example of using the two-stage variant in a situation where the one stage would fail?

Answer (score 1):

The two-stage-version usually finds a nontrivial factor , if there is a prime factor $p$ such that $p-1$ splits into prime factors not exceeding B1 and a single prime factor that is not exceeding B2 (often 100 times B1, but we can choose this B2 also larger).

This , of course , improves the chance to find a prime factor.

I do not know the details of stage 2 (because I only understood stage 1), but stage 2 must be faster than it would be the case if we simply would increase B1. Otherwise stage 2 would not make sense.

Comment: Why not just use the normal version and increase the bound $B$?

Comment: @northerner I edited my answer

Comment: I just found something on the Wikipedia page that confuses me: "A variant of the basic algorithm is sometimes used; instead of requiring that p − 1 has all its factors less than B, we require it to have all but one of its factors less than some B1, and the remaining factor less than some B2 ≫ B1"...I don't understand "requiring that p − 1 has all its factors less than B" for example with B=2 you can still factor 3 out of 15 so this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: If the B1-method already finds a factor, of course the B2-part can be omitted. But with this refinement, we can find significant more factors. So, p-1 of course need not have the large extra prime factor, but the extended method can also find the factor if the extra prime factor exists.

Comment: Does the single stage version of p-1 require the bound to be greater than the largest prime factor of k-1 where k is some factor of the number being factored? I come to this conclusion because of the example [presented on this page](https://programmingpraxis.com/2010/03/19/extending-pollards-p-1-factorization-algorithm/) and because of @OscarSmith's example that contains the trivial factor of 2 yet he says the bound must be at least 17. Is my statement correct or am I mistaking?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know some people get offended by comments so just let me know if you're no longer interested.

Comment: @northerner: stage 1 will succeed if all the following are true:  1) for each prime t and exponent s in the prime power factorization of p-1, t\**s <= B, and 2) the previous condition 1) applied to q-1 is false.

Comment: stage 2 appears to take advantage of the fact that the *difference* between consecutive prime is small (a conjectured upper bound is provided in the article) to eliminate the modular exponentiation at each step of stage 2, at the cost of precomputing a table of powers of H.

Answer (score 0):

The basic reason to use the 2 stage version is that a significant amount of numbers have all but 1 factor small. Since P-1 won't be the last factorization technique you will use, the question is what bounds for B1 and B2 will get the highest anime of non-primes for the least effort.

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding your explanation. Is the 2 stage version faster than just increasing the bound $B$ on the 1 stage version? Are you able to give an example?

Comment: Consider 102=2*3*17. With stage 1, you would need a bound of 17, but with stage 2, you only need B1=3, B2=17 which is much faster

Comment: What calculation are you doing where 1-stage version needs bound of 17? When I do it $a$ starts at 2. Right there GCD(2, 102) gives a factor.

Comment: Are you not saying that 102 is the input number but 103 is one of the factors of the input number? Is that your example?

Comment: yeah, I think that's it